# Matter.js - option to add html to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, matter.js

I am trying out [matter js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) to create objects (bodies) falling to gravity. Below is my sample code used to create. I want to add a hyperlink on top of this body so that user can click on created body and navigate. Is there a way to add or append HTML code to body created in Matter JS.

```
    var phone = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(600, 200, 65, 45,  {
        id : 'phoneBody',
    density: 30.04,
    friction: 10.01,
    frictionAir: 0.00001,
    restitution: 0.2,

    render: {
        fillStyle: '#F35e66',
        strokeStyle: 'black',
        lineWidth: 1,
        sprite: {
                    texture: './images/phone.png'
                }
    }
});
Matter.World.add(world, phone);
```

Comment: I suggest using the DOM for links: [Matter.js Text inside a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681437/matter-js-text-inside-a-rectangle/72849141#72849141) and [Using Matter.js to render to the DOM or React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906218/using-matter-js-to-render-to-the-dom-or-react/65354225#65354225) can be easily modified to use an `<a>` tag, which will be accessible to users with visual impairments and respond to tabindex.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring **hyperlink** to a body in [Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) is a custom implementation (i.e. [event handling](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Event_handling) to provide interactivity feature like hyperlinking).

This custom implementation will involve the following:

1. Define Url for a given body
2. Declare mouse event-handler for interactivity (i.e. reacting to on mouseup events)

---

### Implementation Details

Url can be defined for a given body, as shown below:.

```
var phone = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(30, 50, 35, 55, {
              id : 'phoneBody',
              density: 30.04,
              friction: 0.15,
              frictionAir: 0.15,
              restitution: 0.2,
              render: { 
                fillStyle: '#F35e66',
                strokeStyle: 'black',
                lineWidth: 1
              },
              url: "https://www.phone.com"
            });
```

Now, you need to declare mouse event-handler in-order to interact with bodies present in the world.

This is done in two stages: 
  (i) Declare mouse-interactive object & add it to the world 
  (ii) Declare a On-Mouseup Event-Handler to provide hyperlinking feature

```
// Create a Mouse-Interactive object & add it to the World
render.mouse = Matter.Mouse.create(render.canvas);
var mouseInteractivity = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
                          mouse: render.mouse,
                          constraint: {
                            stiffness: 0.2,
                            render: { visible: false }
                          }
                         });
Matter.World.add(engine.world, mouseInteractivity);

// Create a On-Mouseup Event-Handler
Events.on(mouseInteractivity, 'mouseup', function(event) {
  var mouseConstraint = event.source;
  var bodies = engine.world.bodies;
  if (!mouseConstraint.bodyB) {
    for (i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) { 
      var body = bodies[i];
      if (Matter.Bounds.contains(body.bounds, mouseConstraint.mouse.position)) {
        var bodyUrl = body.url;
        console.log("Body.Url >> " + bodyUrl);
        // Hyperlinking feature
        if (bodyUrl != undefined) {
          window.open(bodyUrl, '_blank');
          console.log("Hyperlink was opened");
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Feel free to play around with above implementation on CodePen >> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQEaQX?editors=0011

> **Note!** In-order for the hyperlink to work, please don't forget to disable the pop-up blocker on your favourite web-browser.